# ТикТок или тикток?

Tags: орфография, прописная-строчная

Как правильно: *тикток* или *ТикТок*? Во всех сайтах пишут, что нужны две заглавные буквы, но я сомневаюсь. Может, вообще не нужно заглавных или нужно заглавными, но в кавычках по принципу *«Фейсбук» — фейсбук* и т. д. Можно ли по такому же принципу писать *«ТикТок» — тикток*?

Answer (score 1):

> [№ 308514](https://gramota.ru/poisk?query=%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA&mode=spravka)
> Здравствуйте. Как по-русски правильно пишется название социальной сети TikTok: Тикток (без дефиса) или Тик-ток (с дефисом)? На официальном сайте русского сегмента соцсети во всех документах указывается только английское, оригинальное, название. Спасибо за ответ.
>
> ОТВЕТ
> Правильного и неправильного варианта написания этого названия пока нет. Оно еще только осваивается русским языком.

Но я бы не стал так однозначно утверждать. Нужно придерживаться официального написания: TikTok (ТикТок). Хотя оно противоречит нормам русского языка (но ср. закрепившееся написание: МегаФон).
Что касается строчной, соглашусь с вами: в бытовом употреблении лучше писать ***тикток*** (по аналогии «Фейсбук» — фейсбук).

Comment: Добрый вечер, Серж. Давненько не пересекались. Я подправила ваш ответ и внесла ссылку. Надеюсь, что Вы не против... Проверьте — всё ли соответствует вашей задумке?

Comment: @Римма Михайлова, конечно, не против! Спасибо!